# Asynchronous execution of sub-states in parallel instances of spring state machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I am trying to create a few instances of state machine from one uml-model. I use stateMachineFactory. I would like these machines working independently and asynchrously.

Everything work great if I use only "base" states. Machine instances can independently go to stateB and StateC. However, when I use regions and sub-states (stateD), machine instances execute action (insideStateD1) one after another. Please look at [image: diagram][1].

I've found that states are executed via stateMachineTaskExecutor (which default is SyncTaskExecutor) but substates are executed via taskScheduler (which default is ConcurrentTaskScheduler).

This is configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class StateMachineConfig extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {

    @Autowired
    StateMachineComponentResolver<String, String> stateMachineComponentResolver;

    @Bean
    public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory() {
        UmlStateMachineModelFactory umlStateMachineModelFactory = new UmlStateMachineModelFactory("classpath:uml/testSM1.uml");
        umlStateMachineModelFactory.setStateMachineComponentResolver(stateMachineComponentResolver);
        return umlStateMachineModelFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineModelConfigurer<String, String> model) throws Exception {
        model
                .withModel()
                .factory(modelFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<String, String> config) throws Exception {
        config
                .withConfiguration()
               // .taskExecutor()  // I tried various taskExecutors
               // .taskScheduler() // I tried various taskSchedulers
                ;
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to achieve many instances of state machine from the same model?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple instances of a SM can be obtained by the [StateMachineFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/StateMachineFactory.html#getStateMachine--).

```
stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(); //builds a new state machine
```

The configuration that you have created in [StateMachineConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/StateMachineConfig.html) applies to all SM instances.

Spring State Machine uses [`TaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) for region executions (doesn't matter top level or nested regions) and by default it's synchronous. To achieve async execution you need to override the default task executor. This can be achieved in the configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config) throws Exception {
    config
        .withConfiguration()
            //other configs
            .taskExecutor(myAsyncTaskExecutor())
}

public TaskExecutor myAsyncTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

or by declaring a bean:

```
@Bean(name = StateMachineSystemConstants.TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

[`TaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) is used for action executions (actions associated with states or transitions) and not for sub-states.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer inspired me to check a few things. I created two classes implementing interface Action and added its to state machine by StateMachineComponentResolver: action associated with transition fire StateA->StateB) and action associated with stateC (function behaviour: insideStateC).  I've found that TaskExecutor is used for actions associated with transitions and guards but TaskScheduler is used for action executions associated with states. Am I right? I had to override TaskScheduler (changed on ThreadPoolTaskScheduler).

Comment: Yes, if you want your actions to be executed in async manner, you have to override the default taskScheduer with one spawning multiple threads.